# How does one verify that an APK has not been tampered with?

Tags: android, apk

A vanilla Android rom (AOSP) does not contain Google Apps. If I download Google Apps from another source, how can I verify that it has not been tampered with ?

Comment: You may find some solutions here. http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9312/how-can-i-verify-the-authenticity-of-an-apk-file-i-downloaded

Answer (score 4):

Each apk is signed with release key. If apk is de-compiled and recompiled then new apk must be signed with a different release key (as each release key need a password which only developer/company know). So you can verify the authenticity of your apk by checking the sha1 of your key. Hope it helps

EDIT:
You must use web services to verify validity of your app(like what facebook does)

1. You must execute this on your release key to get key hash of your app ie.**keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator.android\debug.keystore" | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary |"C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" base64**.
2. Obtained key hash must be saved at your server and must be fetched using web services.
3. Obtain key hash programmatically using the  following code. Verify if both values are same.

   ```
   try {
       PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
               "com.play.fabin",  //Replace your package name here
               PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);

       for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
           MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
           md.update(signature.toByteArray());
           Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
           System.out.println("key hash = " + Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
       }
   } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();

   } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```

Hope it helps you..

Comment: But how will you know what the sha1 hash is supposed to be in the first place ? And also how do you do this in practice ?

Comment: I have edited the answer. Check if this is what you are looking.

Comment: Are you saying one should install the package on an android device first, and then run your code on the device ? Isn't that risky ? And how do you know what the sha1 hash was supposed to be in the first place ?

Comment: This is the best I have come up with. And Users must also be careful where they download their apk from.

Comment: But how do you know what the sha1 hash is supposed to be in the first place ?

Comment: Like I said in my first step, you must generate sha1 of your release key and save it in your server(using java keytool on your release key). If someone decompiled your app then after altering the must recompile it which will require release key. Unless the hacker uses your release key to recompile the app(your release key is protected by your password), the recompiled apk will have different sha1 for its release key(different from your release key).

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question - I am not trying to verify that MY apk is authentic. I am trying to verify if a third party SDK is authentic. AOSP (Android Open Source Program) does not include Google Apps by default. Before I install a third party app (Google Maps) in my rom, I wan't to verify that the Apk is the same one that is present on Google Play, and to do that I need to know what an authentic apk looks like (hash). The question I have been asking is, how does one know what the authentic apk looks like (hash value) ?

Comment: Sorry about that. I too have changed rom couple of times. I downloaded gapps from associated tutorials. But most of the time I can't authenticate if the apk was tampered with. But you can look into gapps made for CyanogenMod. I think they are compatible with AOSP. Check this [link](https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Google_Apps) out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't answer my question - I'm trying to determine if an apk downloaded through a third party site is authentic or not. Just because Cyanogenmod is providing it doesn't mean it is the same as that provided when downloading an app through google play.